# PHP Calculate Unique combinations which total a specific value for multidimensional array

Tags: php, algorithm

In an eCommerce store we have multiple transactions that relate to a specific order, e.g an order was made for 2 SKU's (1 transaction), 2 skus were added (another transaction), 1 was refunded (another transaction).  The order itself is made up of multiple line items, each with a unique id.

Each of these transactions will have a numerical value, where together they will add up to the total of that order.  What I'm trying to achieve is to take the line items and match their values to the transactions where there is no overlap (e.g a line item can only be part of one transaction).

A real world example would be as follows, there are 3 transactions -

- Transaction 1 (6-671461867600)  For 39.68
- Transaction 2 (6-671717458000)  For 31.98
- Transaction 3 (6-671826772048)  For -7.7

(these total 63.96)

And the line items which make up these transactions are as follows.

```
$lineItems = [
  0 =>  [
    "xId" => 96909066320
    "price" => "-7.70"
    "sku" => 'KB-291'
  ]
  1 =>  [
    "xId" => 4978455609424
    "price" => "15.99"
    "sku" => "261-R4-BE3B-CDWM"
  ]
  2 =>  [
    "xId" => 4978455642192
    "price" => "15.99"
    "sku" => "261-LV-5PT8-V6KA"
  ]
  3 =>  [
    "xId" => 4979504119888
    "price" => "15.99"
    "sku" => "261-UQ-3TEP-GJ8U"
  ]
  4 =>  [
    "xId" => 4979504152656
    "price" => "15.99"
    "sku" => "261-SO-58DE-0QKS"
  ]
  5 =>  [
    "xId" => 1887799246928
    "price" => "7.70"
    "sku" => 'KB-297'
  ]
];
```

What I'm trying to achieve is to specify which line items will make up each transaction, doing it manually I can find the follow work with no overlaps.

- Transaction 1)  1887799246928, 4979504152656, 4979504119888
- Transaction 2)  4978455642192, 4978455609424
- Transaction 3)  96909066320

```
$array = [
  "6-671826772048" => [
    0 => "96909066320"
  ]
  "6-671461867600" => [
    0 => "1887799246928,4978455609424,4978455642192"
    1 => "1887799246928,4978455609424,4979504119888"
    2 => "1887799246928,4978455609424,4979504152656"
    3 => "1887799246928,4978455642192,4979504119888"
    4 => "1887799246928,4978455642192,4979504152656"
    5 => "1887799246928,4979504119888,4979504152656"
  ]
  "6-671717458000" => [
    0 => "96909066320,1887799246928,4978455609424,4978455642192"
    1 => "96909066320,1887799246928,4978455609424,4979504119888"
    2 => "96909066320,1887799246928,4978455609424,4979504152656"
    3 => "96909066320,1887799246928,4978455642192,4979504119888"
    4 => "96909066320,1887799246928,4978455642192,4979504152656"
    5 => "96909066320,1887799246928,4979504119888,4979504152656"
    6 => "4978455609424,4978455642192"
    7 => "4978455609424,4979504119888"
    8 => "4978455609424,4979504152656"
    9 => "4978455642192,4979504119888"
    10 => "4978455642192,4979504152656"
    11 => "4979504119888,4979504152656"
  ]
]
```

Where I've got to thus far is for every transaction, find what combination of line items would total the amount of the transaction - however I obviously need to ensure that there is no overlap,

e.g.

- Transaction id 6-671826772048 can ONLY be calculated using Line Item 96909066320.
  -Transaction id 6-671717458000 has an option of being calculated using 96909066320,1887799246928,4979504119888,4979504152656  - however, that would stop Transaction 1 from working.

To sumamrise, I want to take this array

```
$array = [
  "6-671826772048" => [
    0 => "96909066320"
  ]
  "6-671461867600" => [
    0 => "1887799246928,4978455609424,4978455642192"
    1 => "1887799246928,4978455609424,4979504119888"
    2 => "1887799246928,4978455609424,4979504152656"
    3 => "1887799246928,4978455642192,4979504119888"
    4 => "1887799246928,4978455642192,4979504152656"
    5 => "1887799246928,4979504119888,4979504152656"
  ]
  "6-671717458000" => [
    0 => "96909066320,1887799246928,4978455609424,4978455642192"
    1 => "96909066320,1887799246928,4978455609424,4979504119888"
    2 => "96909066320,1887799246928,4978455609424,4979504152656"
    3 => "96909066320,1887799246928,4978455642192,4979504119888"
    4 => "96909066320,1887799246928,4978455642192,4979504152656"
    5 => "96909066320,1887799246928,4979504119888,4979504152656"
    6 => "4978455609424,4978455642192"
    7 => "4978455609424,4979504119888"
    8 => "4978455609424,4979504152656"
    9 => "4978455642192,4979504119888"
    10 => "4978455642192,4979504152656"
    11 => "4979504119888,4979504152656"
  ]
]
```

and ONE result could be (although there are other correct possibilities)

```
$array = [
  "6-671826772048" => "96909066320",
  "6-671461867600 => "4978455642192, 4978455609424"
  "6-671717458000" => "1887799246928, 4979504152656, 4979504119888"
  ];
```

If anyone has an idea on how to solve this it would be appreciated

**Update** - In the example I gave, whilst I presented one combination which solved the problem, there are many, there is no specific link between the transaction and line items, so as long as each transaction line items total the amount, and no transactions share line items, then the problem is considered solved

e.g the following would also be a valid solution

```
$array = [
  "6-671826772048" => "96909066320",
  "6-671461867600" => "4979504152656, 4979504119888"
  "6-671717458000" => "4978455642192, 4978455609424, 1887799246928"
  ];
```

Comment: In order to solve this we will need the target values for the transactions. In case you want to reconstruct the transactions, i have to tell you this wont be possible. Reason: Assume there are 2 transactions both having a total of 10. And there are 2 line-items with a price of 10. You wont be able to tell which one belongs to which - both wlll be valid. Or is there any relation between a line-item or a transaction?

Comment: @Pilan I'll update the question, to answer your question there is no relation between the transaction and the line items (which is why we have to do this) and if course there might be more combinations which work - any combination which solves it with no duplication works - for example - I said transaction id 6-671461867600 could be solved by 4978455642192, 4978455609424 but it also could be solved by 4979504119888 and 4978455642192 (and other combinations)

Comment: so, what have you tried so far? because you should at least show one attempt on solving this yourself. and why are you using strings like `"4978455642192, 4978455609424, 1887799246928"` (sometimes without spaces?) when arrays might be easier to handle? also: is there always a solution and you don't care about which solution it is? (approaches could slightly differ)

Comment: @Jakumi - in terms of solving the problem, this is how far I've got  - the original issue was to find which variations made up the transaction amount I solved this (hence the final array of possibilities).  The code earlier than this found every combination of line items, then added all combinations together and filter by those which matched a transaction, didn't seem much help as at this point its a easier problem to solve.  There would always be a solution, and no we don't care about which solution it is as long as it matches the acceptance criteria (no lines used in more than 1 transaction

Comment: but your original issue doesn't *really* matter right now, as you correctly noted. the current problem has no visible attempts. However, I'd like to mention [array_intersect](https://php.net/array_intersect) and array_merge. The rest is just how to iterate over potential solutions and filtering out those that don't work. I honestly don't see the part where you need actual help with, since you don't seem to *struggle* at anything so far?

Comment: there are still no target-values for transactions. or do you want us to use the examples? [This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)) might be helpful for your attempt.

Comment: What have you tried so far? There's no code given in your question. Additionally, how is this related to Symfony after all?